# How do I find my cars in GTA Online after I accidentally downgraded to a smaller garage?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

So I feel really stupid right now, but I recently owned a 6-car garage, and I wanted 2 more cars, but mine was full. I simply thought, "Oh, I'll just buy another 2-car garage and put them in there." (I use an old TV, so reading things is a little difficult, and I mainly skip over things.)

After I bought a 2-car garage, I realized my other one was gone. I am not allowed to buy it back anymore, even though I have enough money. Some cars transferred but not all, and some of the ones that I lost are worth a lot of money.

I can still use my old cars in races, but I can't find them anywhere else. I've searched for answers to this problem, but no one seems to have made the same lame mistake as me.

Comment: I think you mean GTA Online.

Answer (score 6):

> I use an old tv so reading things are a little difficult and I mainly skip over things.

You should probably stop doing that :)

> I am not allowed to buy it back anymore even though I have enough money. Some cars transferred but not all, some that I lost are worth a lot of money.

You haven't lost any cars, you just can't access more than what fits in your current garage. If you buy another 6-car or 10-car garage, you will get access to all the cars again.

Answer (score 1):

If you transfer from a 10-car garage, for example, down to a six-car garage, you will need to put those six cars into slots 1-6 first. If you forget, go back and buy a 10-car garage, then rearrange. Your cars should still be there.

Answer (score 0):

The user who posted this Reddit /r/GTAOnline post had a similar predicament to yours: [I accidentally hurriedly bought a property and lost a full 10 car garage](https://www.reddit.com/r/gtaonline/comments/11wjwvd/fuck_i_accidentally_hurriedly_bought_a_property/).

Another user [provided a solution](https://www.reddit.com/r/gtaonline/comments/11wjwvd/fuck_i_accidentally_hurriedly_bought_a_property/jcy9umh/) that the original poster confirmed resolved their issue (emphasis mine):

> You didn't really lose anything. The cars are simply in storage now. **They can be requested with the mechanic and then put into empty slots in other garages.**