# My Zentorno disappeared in GTA V online

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I was collecting some cars in my garage and it appeared to me that it was full, so it asked me to select a car to exchange it and I chose the Zentorno. I tried to get it back, please tell me how.

Answer (score 1):

Go buy a larger garage and your cars shall appear.

> You haven't lost any cars, you just can't access more than fit in your current garage. If you buy another 6-car or 10-car garage you will get access to all the cars again.

[How do I find my cars in GTA Online after I accidentally downgraded to a smaller garage?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/139357/how-do-i-find-my-cars-in-gta-online-after-i-accidentally-downgraded-to-a-smaller)

`Possible duplicate of question linked above.`

Comment: I bought it and nothing happened

Comment: So i dont have my Zentorno anymore? I exchanged it for a truck...

Comment: If i tell to rockstar will them do something?

Comment: They have account back ups. Tell them what happened they may undo your error.

Comment: Thats great! Just so others know what did you do?

Comment: I sent a Tweet to Rockstar support asking for help and they told me to put the problem in a ticket (they sent me the link) so i posted the ticket and tweeted that it was done and they checked it and gave it back. So if you use twitter they will answer almost in 5 mins.